# What does a negative plan discount mean on a medical insurance claim in the United States?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, medical-bill, discount

I saw the following medical insurance (Aetna) claim in the United States:

[image]

What does the negative plan discount mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A plan discount is a pre-negotiated rate a medical service provider has with an insurance company. Oftentimes they are in the form of price caps for specific services, or perhaps as a percentage discount.

The claim you're seeing is a little confusing because you aren't seeing the original price. If you view the bill from the service provider it will probably make more sense and look like this:

```
Service Cost: $120
Plan discount: -$10
Insurance Paid: $0
Your cost: $110
```

So, even though your insurance didn't cover this service, their negotiated rate did help reduce the cost for you.

**Side Note:** I've seen Plan discounts reduce the cost by more than 50% before, for example taking a $1000 service down to $400. It really makes you wonder how the service prices are calculated in the first place, and I also wonder who actually pays full price. (I know it's common for uninsured patients to be given huge discounts too.)

Comment: "I also wonder who actually pays full price." As with the "$900" suits on sale for $150 at JCPenney, the answer here is essentially "no one".